# How to change azure-pipeline network while executing?

Tags: azure, maven, azure-devops, sonarqube, azure-pipelines

I have a project with two components, one component needs on public network and another component works on private network.

So if I give in application.yml as follows then the first component fails

```
pool:
  vmImage: windows-latest
  name: private-network
```

But if I give the pool without CBS then the second component fails

```
pool:
  vmImage: windows-latest
  #name: private-network
```

How to solve this? How to switch the network while the pipeline is running?

Answer (score 0):

You can use multiple stages to run your pipelines in Private and Public Network in your yaml script like below:-

```yaml
trigger:

- main

stages:

- stage: Public

jobs:

- job: PublicJob

pool:

vmImage: windows-latest

steps:

- script: |

# Run the component that needs public network access

echo "Running component on public network"

- stage: Private

dependsOn: Public

jobs:

- job: PrivateJob

pool:

name: private-network

steps:

- script: |

# Run the component that needs private network access

echo "Running component on private network"
```

[image]

In the private network, Add the name of your private pool and use both pools in a multi-stage pipeline like the above and run.

Alternatively, You can also reference both these pools in a variable in azure DevOps and use it whenever needed for your pipeline in a runtime.

Comment: Thank you so much, will try this and let you know.

Comment: Hello Siddhesh, how to remove the private network name afterwards? Let's say I need private network for job 1 and public network for job 2. Now what should the be the pool name: ??